# Print nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have multiple dictionaries in JSON file that I want to process.

```
data = [
    {
        'field1' : 'Name',
        'value': {
            'self': 'www.google.com',
            'id': '1234',
            'value': 'myname'
        }
    },
    {
        'field1' : 'Name1',
        'value': {
            'self': 'www.google.com',
            'id': '2345',
            'value': 'myname1'
        }
    },
    {
        'field1' : 'Name2',
        'value': 'hostname'
    }
]
```

I have tried:

```
for info in data:
  if 'value' in info:
     if isinstance(info, dict)
       print(info['value']['value'])
```

I got the output as:

```
myname
myname1
```

I am looking for below output:

```
myname
myname1
hostname
```

Comment: You have the `if` but you forgot the `else`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it:

```
data = [
    {
        'field1' : 'Name',
        'value': {
            'self': 'www.google.com',
            'id': '1234',
            'value': 'myname'
        }
    },
    {
        'field1' : 'Name1',
        'value': {
            'self': 'www.google.com',
            'id': '2345',
            'value': 'myname1'
        }
    },
    {
        'field1' : 'Name2',
        'value': 'hostname'
    }
]


def deepest_string_value(d):
    value = d.get('value')   
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return deepest_string_value(value)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return value
    

for row in data:
    print(deepest_string_value(row))
```

Output:

```
myname
myname1
hostname
```